# Replacing part of String one by one

Tags: android, string, replace, contains

I have string:

> Apple, Banana, Strawberry; Lemon, Watermelon; Orange

When I try this:

```
if(meaning.contains(";"))
        {
            meaning=meaning.replace(";", "\n");
        }
```

Result:

```
Apple, Banana, Strawberry  
 Lemon, Watermelon  
 Orange
```

How to replace part of String one by one in order to replace ";" to "\n"+numStr?

```
1.Apple, Banana, Strawberry  
2.Lemon, Watermelon  
3.Orange
```

Comment: So, you are trying to number the split string results?

Comment: Yes, exactly like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't test it, but should work:

```
String[] lines = meaning.split(";");
StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0, size = lines.length; i < size; i++) {
    res.append(i + 1).append(". ").append(lines[i]).append("\n");
}
res.toString();
```

Comment: @JoeRichard, in this case you should change the line `res.append((i + 1) + ". " + lines[i] + "\n");` to `res.append(i+1).append(". ").append(lines[i]).append("\n")` to make full use of the efficiency of `StringBuilder`. Otherwise it really defeats the purpose of using it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code. The trick is to use `String.split()` instead of `String.replace()`.

```
if(meaning.contains(";"))
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String[] meanings = meaning.split(";");
    for (int i = 0; i < meanings.length; i++) {
        builder.append(String.format(Locale.US, "%d. %s\n", i, meanings[i].trim()));
    }
    Log.d("meanings", builder.toString());
}
```

The result will print:

> 1.Apple, Banana, Strawberry
>   2.Lemon, Watermelon
>   3.Orange